# Alternative to nesting when performing a left join and multiple inner joins

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

Consider the following fictitious scenario:

[image: Entity relationship diagram]

How would I go about getting a list of all the categories (distinct or otherwise, it doesn't matter) for each customer, even if a customer hasn't ordered any products?

Also assume that we don't have navigation properties, so we'll need to use manual joins.

This is my attempt which uses nesting:

```
var customerCategories = from c in context.Customers
                         join o in context.Orders on c.CustomerId equals o.CustomerId into orders
                         select new
                         {
                             CustomerName = c.Name,
                             Categories = (from o in orders
                                           join p in context.Products on o.ProductId equals p.ProductId
                                           join cat in context.Category on p.CategoryId equals cat.CategoryId
                                           select cat)
                         };
```

Is there a different (possibly better way) to achieve the same outcome?

**Alternative: Multiple Left (Group) Joins**

```
var customerCategories = from customer in context.Customers
                         join o in context.Orders on customer.CustomerId equals o.CustomerId into orders
                         from order in orders.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join p in context.Products on order.ProductId equals p.ProductId into products
                         from product in products.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join cat in context.Categories on product.CategoryId equals cat.CategoryId into categories
                         select new
                         {
                             CustomerName = c.Name,
                             Categories = categories
                         };
```

Comment: Which linq-to-xxx is this? And which navigation properties are there? You can probably do this without any manually written join clause.

Comment: It is linq-to-entities, however that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Why do you really need to join, if a customer hasn't got any products. A business scenario would either be get the categories of products bought by the customer, or get all categories. In your case it seems that you want to display all categories, so no need of join.

Answer (score 2):

I recreated your table structure and added some data so that I could get a better idea what you were trying to do.  I found a couple of ways to accomplish what you want but I'm just going to add this method.  I think it's the most concise and I think it's pretty clear.

**Code**

```
var summaries = Customers.GroupJoin(Orders,
    cst => cst.Id,
    ord => ord.CustomerId,
    (cst, ord) => new { Customer = cst, Orders = ord.DefaultIfEmpty() })
    .SelectMany(c => c.Orders.Select(o => new
        {
            CustomerId = c.Customer.Id,
            CustomerName = c.Customer.Name,
            Categories = Categories.Where(cat => cat.Id == c.Customer.Id)
        }));
```

**Output**

[image: LINQ Output]

**Table Structure**

[image: Table Structure]

**Table Data**

[image: Table Data]

Answer (score 0):

If you need all categories couldn't you just:

```
Categories = (from c in context.Category 
                      select cat)
```

Comment: Maybe it's a bit unclear, but the example I used is fictitious, and exists purely to express the left join followed by inner joins required.

Comment: An inner join will always filter the results. If you need a table( or entity in this case) you will always have to start with the one you want as a whole, and use left joins onwards.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually perfectly correct. I did try this before with no luck. This time I included added DefaultIfEmpty() on the groups and it did actually do the left joins. Could you update your answer to explain this instead and maybe give an example?

Comment: Sorry, i was away. What example do you need?